# How can I change dpi inline code output in notebook Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I know how to change the dpi of a plot when knitting a rmarkdown notebook to html. However is there a way to change the dpi of a plot generated in a rmarkdown notebook without having to knit the document, id est the plot is shown as inline output between two code chunks while working on the notebook?

Comment: Look at the `knitr` docs: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots You can set chunk options for the plotting device and dpi for individual chunks, which I believe should take effect each time you run that chunk

Comment: Unfortunately the preview does not respect that option. I am having the same problem and posted it on the Rstudio forum here https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-markdown-chunks-dpi-option-ignored-on-run-current-chunk/34038/4.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, and I created a bug report here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11649. Make sure to give it a "thumbs up" so it gets attention.